# Confusion about spectral measure of operator in tracial von Neumann algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

The setting is that $(M, \tau)$ is a tracial von Neumann algebra ($\tau$ is a faithful, normal tracial state) that is a subset of the bounded operators on a Hilbert space $H$. Let $x \in M$ be a self-adjoint operator. Let $\mu_x$ be the spectral measure of $x$ (with respect to $\tau$).

I am a bit confused about where the wrong step in the following "proof" that if $x$ is not invertible (i.e. $0 \in \sigma(x)$) then $\mu_x(\{0\}) > 0$. If this is true, then by considering $x - \lambda$ for $\lambda \in \sigma(x)$, it seems we would get that $\sigma(x)$ could only contain countably many points, which is false in general.

Suppose that $x$ does not have a bounded inverse in $M$, or equivalently that $x$ is not bijective.

For a self adjoint $x \in M$, it is a fact that $\chi_{\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}}(x)$ is equal to the projection onto the closure of the image of $x$ (or, equivalently the orthogonal complement to the kernel of $x$).

Hence, for $x$ to not be invertible, $\chi_{\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0 \}}(x) \neq 1$. As $\chi_{\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}}(x) + \chi_{\{0\}}(x) = 1$, this means that $\chi_{ \{0\}}(x)$ is a non-zero projection. From faithfulness of $\tau$, then $\tau(\chi_{ \{0\}}(x)) > 0$ and hence $\mu_x(\{0\}) > 0$.

Comment: $\chi_{\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}}$ is, as you mentioned, the projection onto the *closure* of the image of $x$. So $x$ doesn't need to be surjective to have $\chi_{\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}} = 1$, it just needs to have *dense* range. If the range is dense but not everything, $x$ is still not invertible.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the very fast reply! Ok, I think I get it now, I was using an "equivalence" that is not actually an equivalence. It is always true that if $x$ is invertible, then $\chi_{\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}}(x) = 1$, but the converse is false in general. In this situation I tried to use the contrapositive of the converse, if $x$ is not invertible, then $\chi_{\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}}(x) \neq 1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As David said in the comments, the statement:

"for $x$ not to be invertible, $\chi_{\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\} }(x) \neq 1$" is not correct. It could be possible that $x$ is not invertible and the kernel of $x$ is $\{0\}$ and the image of $x$ has dense range (but not all of $H$), so then $\chi_{\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\} }(x) = 1$.

Basically I assumed the converse of: "if $x$ is invertible, then $\chi_{\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\} }(x) = 1$"

Comment: Indeed, there's no reason that the converse is true. As an example, think multiplication by $x$ on $L^2([0, 1])$ (which is contained in the tracial vNa $L^\infty([0, 1])$). Then it is not surjective. Indeed, the constant function $1$ is not in the range, as $1/x \notin L^2([0, 1])$, so in particular it is not invertible. But it does have dense range - every function supported away from $0$ is in the range - and trivial kernel - since the Dirac delta function at $0$ is not in $L^2$, so $\chi_{\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}} = 1$ and $\chi_{\{0\}} = 0$.